# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: xslt

I am getting the error posted in the title.

This works:

```
<xsl:variable name= "data">
    <xsl:value-of select="abc"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

But when I try to add variable to a href doesn't work with the following code:

```
<a href="../depts/"{$data}".html"><xsl:value-of select="group"/></a>
```

I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have invalid XML because of the quotes around `{$data}` here:

```
<a href="../depts/"{$data}".html"> ... </a>
                  ^       ^
```

Do you really need these quotes? Isn't this what you want?

```
<a href="../depts/{$data}.html"> ... </a>
```